# Getting an error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

Why do I keep getting error that I am not in root directory of project and there is no `pubspec.yaml` file even though I am in the root directory of the project where the `pubspec.yaml` file is present in the root directory.

This problem don't let me start with Flutter.

I tried changing directory and every possible thing found on Stack Overflow.

UPDATE:
Fixed it by deleting autoplay at path 'Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor' in Registry Editor
Thanks to everyone who helped :)

Comment: please edit to add version info for all your things and more concrete proof that what you are saying that you observe is true.

Answer (score 0):

Use the corresponding command in your terminal

Linux/PowerShell: ls

Command Prompt: dir

Can you confirm that the pubspec appears in the output list and paste the name back to us?